# AWS Cognito SMS Verification - Changing OTP expiry time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there anyway I can change the expiry time set to the verification code sent through SMS (Or Email) by AWS Cognito?

By default, the verification code expires in 24 hours which is not convenient in the case where there is a time limit in the app to verify your mobile/Email.

There isn't really anything useful from the AWS Cognito documentations or developer's guide.

Comment: It's not possible to customize the expiry time.

Comment: Any update? Did you fix?

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs, we can not change OTP expiry.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-sms-text-message.html

Answer (score 0):

> To adjust this period, change your app client Authentication flow session duration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).